# Getting the "full" installation with tlmgr

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

Does "full" installation really mean full?  I did one, but

```
tlmgr info
```

shows quite a few packages as not installed.  Is this because my
installation went wrong?  Should every single line have an "i"
to the left?

Should I now just run

```
tlmgr info --data name | tlmgr install
```

to get a full installation?

Comment: `tlmgr update --all` ? or `install` rather than `update`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, neither `tlmgr install` nor `tlmgr install --all` works.  And `update --all` seems to work only with packages that are already installed.

Comment: Please quantify "shows quite a few packages as not installed". I have a full MacTeX2020 installation. But if I run `tlmgr info`, quite a few items are mentioned as not being installed on my system. However, the not-installed items are not packages at all; instead, they are executables for architectures other than `x86_64-darwin` (for MacOS). AFAICT, it's entirely appropriate that 15 out of the  16 versions of the `a2ping`, `accfonts`, `adhocfilelist`, etc executables are NOT installed on my MacOS system.

Comment: Another possible is those new packages uploaded to CTAN _after_ the TeX Live 2020 iso file is prepared.